# Decoupling delete modal from button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I've put together a sample I am working on where I want to decouple my dialogue Modal from the delete button. I'm running into trouble trying to think of how I can restructure the components while still keeping functionality. Ideally the modal should be rendered once and be modular. Data passed into it should change during the request to show the modal.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-l8hbdr

Right now I believe a delete modal is created for every single button which is horribly inefficient. I've heard using references are bad and using Redux for this seems overkill. Maybe I should use a React portal?

Where should the modal be rendered from? I'd like a reusable modal and I found this [guide](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/modal-components-react-custom-hooks), however I don't know where I should be storing the Modal component and how data should pass into it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with [props drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling) in your code

For example, `expenses` and `updateExpenses` are passed from `<Main />` to `DisplayExpenses` and then passed to `<DeleteExpense />`, if the app is getting bigger, this will make the code hard to maintain. I think you can put `const [expenses, updateExpenses] = React.useState(...)` from `<Main />` to `<DisplayExpenses />`.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Col, Card, Row, Button } from "antd";
import uuid from 'react-uuid'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import addExpense from '../utilities/AddExpense';
import DeleteExpense from '../utilities/DeleteExpense';

const Sentencer = require('sentencer');

export default function DisplayExpenses(props) {
    // move expenses from <Main /> to <DisplayExpenses />
    const [expenses, updateExpenses] = React.useState([
        {
            "id": uuid(),
            "name": Sentencer.make("{{ noun }}"),
            "amount": 53.22,
        },
        {
            "id": uuid(),
            "name": Sentencer.make("{{ noun }}"),
            "amount": 76.16,
        },
        {
            "id": uuid(),
            "name": Sentencer.make("{{ noun }}"),
            "amount": 716.16,
        },
    ]);

    const ListOfExpenses = () => {

        return expenses.map((index) => {

            return (
                <Col key={index.id}>
                    <Card
                        key={index.id}
                        title={index.name}
                        bordered={true}
                        style={{ width: "100%", border: "1px solid black" }}
                        actions={[

                            <DeleteExpense
                                key={index.id}
                                id={index.id}
                                name={index.name}
                                amount={index.amount}
                                updateExpensesFn={updateExpenses}
                                expenses={expenses} />
                        ]}
                    >
                        <p key={index.id}>Amount: {index.amount}</p>
                    </Card>
                </Col>

            )
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Row gutter={[16, 8]}>

                <ListOfExpenses />
                <Button
                    type="primary"
                    style={{ margin: "5% 5%" }}
                    onClick={() => addExpense({ expenses, updateExpensesFn: updateExpenses})}
                >
                    Add Expense
                </Button>


            </Row>
        </>
    );
}
```

if you want to render `<DeleteModal />` only once instead of every single button, you can adjust `<DeleteExpense />` slightly, make `<DeleteModal />` rendered only when `modalVisibleBool` is true

```
{modalVisibleBool && (
  <DeleteModal
    showModal={modalVisibleBool}
    onOkay={() => onConfirmDelete({
      updateExpensesFn: props.updateExpensesFn,
      expenses: props.expenses,
      expenseToDelete
    })}
    cancelFn={() => onCancelDeleteModal()}
    expenseToDelete={expenseToDelete}
  />
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In its current state, I don't see the Modals being created in the underlying HTML which is unexpected, do you know why they don't get created? And if the && is still needed?

If I wanted to maintain the list of expenses in a central location, what would you recommend?

Comment: This is normal. modal will be rendered in HTML only when the visible state is true. && operator is just control react don't create `<DeleteModal />` instance if visible state is false. and if you want to maintain expenses in a central location,  you can move the delete and add logic from `<AddExpense />` and `<DeleteExpense />` into `<DisplayExpenses />`.

Comment: I think your question is related to this, you can take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)